# Is there a closed form for the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{e^{x}+1} d x$ where $n\in R^+.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

When I first met the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^{x}+1} d x$, I started to investigate it in terms of power series. After evaluating the integral using integration by parts, I write a [post in Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-evaluate-the-integral-displaystyle-int_0-infty-frac-x-e-x-1-dx-tag/answer/Lai-Johnny?ch=17&oid=285860903&share=8cc89bc2&srid=CCOmo&target_type=answer)

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^{x}+1} d x =\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)= \frac{\pi^{2}}{12}. \tag{1} $$

After a while, I encountered  another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4002633/732917) which use one more partner integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{e^{x}-1}dx $$and found that\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{e^{x}+1}dx=\frac{3}{2}\zeta\left(  3\right)
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

These two results urges me to generalize it as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{e^{x}+1}dx=K\zeta\left(  n+1\right) \tag{3} $$

---

Proof:
\begin{aligned}
I_{n} &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n} e^{-x}}{1+e^{x}} d x \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} e^{-k x} d x\\&= =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n} e^{-(k+1) x} d x}_{J_{k}}
\end{aligned}

Applying integration by parts on $J_n$ yields a reduction formula

$$
\begin{aligned}
J_{k} &=-\frac{1}{k+1} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n} d\left(e^{-(k+1) x}\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{k+1}\left[\frac{x^{n}}{e^{(k+1) x}}\right]_{0}^{\infty}+\frac{n}{k+1} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n-1} e^{-(k+1) x} d x \\
&=\frac{n}{k+1} J_{k-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the formula $n$ times gives $$
J_{k}=\frac{n}{k+1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{k+1} \cdots \frac{1}{k+1} J_{0}=\frac{n !}{(k+1)^{n+1}}
$$
Then we can generalize successfully that $$
\begin{aligned}
I_{n} &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} n !}{(k+1)^{n+1}} \\
&=n ! \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{n+1}} \\&=\boxed{\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right) n !\zeta(n+1)}
\end{aligned}
$$

***My Question***

How about when $n$ is ***not*** a natural number? Your opinions and alternate solutions are warmly welcome.

Comment: This is a [well-known result](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.5.E3).

Comment: [$:\![|||||]\!:$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111551/improper-integral-of-xn-ex1-where-n-is-an-integer) (really asked [zillion](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5En%7D%7Be%5Ex%2B1%7Ddx%24&p=1) times)

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the question, I feel that I can use the Gamma function instead of power series and get the answer faster.

Converting the integral $$J_{k} =\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n} e^{-(k+1) x} d x$$

into a Gamma Function by letting $t=(k+1) x$, then

\begin{aligned}J_{k} &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)^{n} e^{-t} d t \\
&=\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n}} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n} e^{-t} d t \\
&=\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n}} \Gamma(n+1) 
\end{aligned}
Hence $$
\boxed{I_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right) \Gamma(n+1) \zeta(n+1),}
$$
where $n$ is ***not*** necessarily a natural number but $\Re(n)>0$.

Comment: indeed, and working along similar lines (you already seem to have all the algebraic steps in your question), one can show that for any $\text{Re}(s)>0$, we have $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^s}{e^x+1}\,dx=(1-2^{-s})\Gamma(1+s)\zeta(1+s)$.

Comment: After I finish the proof, I found that n is not necessarily a natural number.

Comment: @Lai You could have come to the same conclusion if you had taken a look at the link I provided.